# Microsoft Graph API batch request with dependencies?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Can I make several requests batched that rely on each other? For example, get the recent items and get the embed link for each of them. The second request relies on the first because it requires the ID of the item to get the link.

Is that even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is possible in Microsoft Graph today but I encourage you to submit a UserVoice feature request at https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests?category_id=359563